# Why does cifs asks for su rights to write any data into it?

Tags: linux, permissions, mount, cifs, su

I'm mounting a windows share as follows:

```
sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.178.49/public -o users,username=name,dom=domain,password=pword /mnt/nas
```

Then I'm trying to create a simple file with some basic text:

```
touch /mnt/nas/me.txt
```

And get an error, however, the file is created (contains 0B of data though):

```
touch: cannot touch ‘me.txt’: Permission denied
```

With sudo it works flawless. How can I allow my current user to write data to the share? Is there a mount option?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, unless CIFS' Unix extensions are being used by both the client and server, files are owned by root (regardless of who owns them on the server.)  Try adding the `uid=your-user-id` option to fix this.

For more information, see the [mount.cifs manpage](http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/mount.cifs.8.html#id2532725).

Comment: I think it's safer appending also `,gid=YOUR_USERNAME`.

Comment: Dang, I just found the solution and came here to write it down :D